# Mongodb export subfield item

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoexport

I have the mongodb data shown below that i'm dumping to csv and works ok to produce this data.

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57770104c6" }, "data" : { "username" : "23359244-649151A3C397",   "loginCount" : 0, "createDate" : "1379193232", "modifiedDate" : "1379193232", "roleId" : 1, "dateOfBirth" : "1379109600", "userProfileStateId" : 5, "cellPhoneVerificationSent" : false, "page" : 0, "limit" : 9, "nameForSearch" : "Jomo Kenyatta" } }
```

I would like to dump only the subfield items results for "nameForSearch" e.g "Jomo Kenyatta" - but i keep getting 0 results. Could anyone point me to something i might be doing wrong?

```
mongoexport -d refugees -c stat -f "data" -q '{"createdAt":{"$gte":new Date(1379192400000)}, "data.nameForSearch" : {$regex: "^name"}}'--csv >  refugees.csv
```

Solved: 
I had to add the subfield or subdoc name to original doc name i.e data.nameForSearch and my results dump on the searches as i wanted.

```
mongoexport -d refugees -c stat -f data.nameForSearch -q '{"createdAt":{"$gte":new Date(1379192400000)}}'--csv >  refugees.csv
```

Comment: In the query, you're using "createdAt" but the key in the database is "createDate". Hope this is not a typo?

Comment: Nop, not a typo. The createAt query is for a different "date" item at the same level with "data" item.

Comment: Solved, i edited the question